# debitum - dette - debt

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, history

I would like to know if there is an explanation for presence of "b" in the word "debt" in the contemporary English. Google says that in Middle English this word was written as "dette". Why then "b" reappeared later again?

[Link to Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=debt+word+origin)

Comment: Questions about etymology and historical usage are better-suited to [english.se], and indeed this specific question is handled in Noldorin's answer to *[Why does English spelling use silent letters?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8883)*. *Doubt*, *February*, *receipt*, *solder*, and *island* are other common examples of spellings chosen to make English look more like Latin— even though *island* has no etymological relation at all to the Latin *isla*.

Answer (score 2):

According to [*debt*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/debt):

> Word origin of 'debt'
>   C13: from Old French *dette*, **from Latin *dēbitum***, from *dēbēre* to owe, from *de- + habēre* to have;
>   **English spelling influenced by the Latin etymon**

What came to my mind at first was [*debit*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/debit) which is more specific:

> Word origin of 'debit'
>   C15: from Latin *dēbitum*